# Named capturing group to different names

Tags: regex, ruby, fluentd

I'm working on a logging stack based on Banzai Cloud ClusterFlow, we've a log that is currently parsed with a regular expression and placed in a specific name; however we would like to deprecate that name and replace it with a new one, let's say the pattern is just like the following one:

`^(?<someName>[^ ]*) (?<someNameWeWishToDeprecate>[^ ]*)$`

supposing we receive a log line such as

`prop1 prop2`

it will produce two properties in our parsed log:

```
someName=prop1
someNameWeWishToDeprecate=prop2
```

What we would like to obtain is instead

```
someName=prop1
someNameWeWishToDeprecate=prop2
someNewFancyNae=prop2
```

As you can see we'd like to keep the old name but also have the new one; is this possible by elaborating the regular expression?

FYI: the regular expression engine is ruby-based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest the named capturing groups and use

```r
^(?<someName>[^ ]*) (?<someNewFancyNae>(?<someNameWeWishToDeprecate>[^ ]*))$
```

Or,

```r
^(?<someName>\S+)\s+(?<someNewFancyNae>(?<someNameWeWishToDeprecate>\S+))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/20cK92/1).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, using the same tool we used to validate the used regex it seems to work fine, we'll schedule more thourough tests but for now this surely is the accepted answer!